# Hide / Show multiple items with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched around and seem to be getting the same answer to all the people who have asked a similar question so please forgive me if it seems simplistic.  I am trying to hide/show multiple items at the same time with the pressing of just one button, and it seems the only way I have come about doing so it by handling it with the class, such as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
$(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
```

and the html as follows

```
<p class="test">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<p class="test">If you click on the "Hide" button, this also disappears.</p>
```

I dont want to do so using an html selector like

```
<p>
```

as in my example because I want to use it for different types of items.

Comment: `$("p.test")` as element

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your answers.  They are very helpful and I will take some time to figure out how exactly to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about using a css class?

```
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $(".class-to-hide").hide();
  });
```

html

```
<div class="class-to-hide">
    <p>will hide</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="class-to-hide">will also hide</p>
</div>
```

there are countless options you could use, just get familiar with your jQuery selectors and take your pick..

- you could use class, which is `$('.something')`
- data-target="something", which is `$('*[data-target="something"]')`
- input type="number", which is `$('input[type="number"]')`

Answer (score 1):

The other option (in addition the answer already presented) is you can use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to hide / show (allows you to use 1 button instead of 2):

```
<p class="test">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<p class="test">If you click on the "Hide" button, this also disappears.</p>
```

will do both hide and show.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("p.test").toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Class Selector (".class")](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

> Selects all elements with the given class.

```
//It will select all paragraph with the given class
$("p.test").hide();
```

You should go through all the [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the class instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".test").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
$(".test").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
```